# Browse documentation doc sets in Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode5

In Xcode **5**, how do I browse the documentation sets?

In Xcode 4, I was able to list and search the sets. See screenshot below for an example:

[image: Xcode 4 documentation doc set browser]

In Xcode 5, I can't view a list, I'm only able to search.

Is it:

- Something obvious I'm missing?
- A *bug*?
- A new *feature*?

Answer (score 4):

You can click on the "documentation and api reference" thing in the help menu.

Comment: And then? I don't see anything helpful when I do that.

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to browse the documentation is a new feature, but backlash against it has changed it from a feature to a bug. If you're a member of one of Apple's paid developer programs, you can download the Xcode 5.0.1 GM Seed and see if that fixes this issue. If not, you'll have to wait for 5.0.1 to be released.

**Update**

With the release of Xcode 5.0.1, I don't have to worry about violating Apple's NDA, and I can say that Xcode 5.0.1 restores documentation browsing. You can browse documentation from the bookmarks list on the left side of the documentation window.

[image]

Comment: 5.0.1 does NOT fix it..  what made you think it would?

Comment: It's mentioned in the release notes. Plus, I was able to browse the documentation with it.

Comment: There are two buttons at the top of the bookmarks list on the left side of the window. One button shows the bookmarks. The other lets you browse the documentation. If you're still having problems, you should post at the paid dev forums since 5.0.1 is still under NDA.